# Disable Excel Workbook connections

Tags: vba, excel

My Excel spreadsheets work through a Shared folder. I have created connections from base files to other files. For example, the customers file is connected with some other documents that need to retrieve this information and be updated.  The thing is, when a secondary file is open I cannot work on the base file since it will open in [Read Only], I tried with the connection properties and figured out that whenever the external data reference hasn't been updated I can work the base files but if another user Refreshes the file I get screwed, I tried this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))

ThisWorkbook.Connections("Test1").OLEDBConnection.EnableRefresh = False

End Sub
```

I thought it would refresh the query and then disable the connection so I won't get the [Read Only], but I'm still getting it.

Answer (score 0):

Just randomly guessing - can you try this:

```
ActiveWorkbook.ExclusiveAccess
```

instead of:

`ThisWorkbook.Connections("Test1").OLEDBConnection.EnableRefresh = False`

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
ThisWorkbook.ConnectionsDisabled
```

Comment: I tried that but, i have a vba error, "the property usage is not valid" :(